# Узнать, что из папки Resources используется в игре. Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть папка Resources в юнити, содержимое который в любом случае попадает в билд и загружается командой
`Resources.Load`

Со временем в такой папке накапливается мусор и неиспользуемые ассеты, но как узнать что они неиспользуемые, если они явно нигде не назначены и зависимостей у них прямых нет? Есть ли какой то хитрый способ найти во всех скриптах `Resources.Load` и узнать или предположить все варианты его вызова, и, возможно на основе этого выяснить какие ассеты нужны, а какие нет. Или каким то иным способом почистить папку ресурсов.

Comment: Можно изначально прилежно всё каталогизировать, а не кидать всё куда попало в стиле все картинки в `/image`, а все шейдеры в `/shaders`. Это то, чему все учатся через боль =D welcome to club!

Comment: @Yaroslav Оно каталогизировано, однако не ясно, какие именно картинки нужно оставить в билде, а какие нет. И не только картинки.

Comment: Как автоматизировать - не знаю. Но более-менее удобный способ посмотреть все вызовы (в VS) - поставить курсор на `.Load` и нажать Shift+F12

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский и результате ты не увидишь ни чего, что указано непосредственно в префабах.

Comment: Вобще можно написать скрипт который пройдётся по всем директориям и составит список всё .png и других интересующих расширений и список всех .cs и .prefub.meta читая которые будет искать совпадения с искомым списком и выдаст все не упомянутые файлы. Причём это не так уж тяжело.

Comment: @Yaroslav не сказал бы, что это просто. Парсинг .meta позволит собрать все ссылки с префабов/SO/etc. Однако `Resources.Load` придется парсить какой-нибудь регуляркой по **всем** скриптам. Это не очень быстро, но это уже другой вопрос. Главная проблема здесь - вложенные объекты, а еще `Resources.Load`, параметром которого является сериализованная строка. Да и еще бы надо проверить случай, когда `Resources.Load` загружает префаб, который тоже может что-то там подцеплять. По отдельности задачи не такие сложные, но вот собрать это все вместе - такое себе)

Comment: А зачем парсить, это лишь груда символов значение которых не важно. Проверяются, как string на содержание искомых substring (имён).

Comment: @Yaroslav не понял, что вы имеете в виду. Если в каком-то скрипте будет строка `Resources.Load("Textures/Texture.png")`, то ее ну никак не найти без парсинга исходного кода.

Comment: string text = File.ReadAllText(someDotCsOrMeta); int index = text.IndexOf("reach.png"); не сработает?

Comment: @Yaroslav так пути заранее неизвестны, нужно будет искать `text.IndexOf("Resources.Load")` и парсить вручную строку, которую в нее передали, да. Регулярка будет работать, скорее всего, медленее, но зато сама все спарсит и отдаст чисто нужные строки внутри `Resources.Load`.